# migrate mysql from windows to unix. syntax error on generated file

Tags: mysql, import, migration

So, I'm trying to move an existing MySQL database from a Win2008 server to an Ubuntu machine, however when I try to import the dump file, MySQL is giving me a syntax error.

Below are the steps I took

1. (on windows machine, in mysql\bin)

   ```
   .\mysqldump.exe -u root -p test > test.sql
   ```
2. (on windows machine, in cygwin)

   ```
    scp test.sql myusername@hostname:~/
   ```
3. (on ubuntu machine)

   ```
   $ mysql
   mysql> create table test2;
   $ mysql -u root -p test2 < test.sql
   ```

MySQL then stalls for a litle bit, and then throws...
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error...

It's as if the error is in the dump file generated by windows.  It is something in character conversion? or formatting? or something that I'm just just missing?

EDIT:

The error was that I needed to run a refresh before running mysqldump.exe.  The command that did the trick was....

```
./mysqladmin.exe -u root -p refresh
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the entire error message as well as the query where it is raised.

Comment: The only error that was generated was the standard run-of-the-mill MySQL syntax error with just a single quote (') about 100 blank lines, and then a closing single quote.

Comment: Did you check your SQL dump to see if it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, the file made sense, it was too large to fully parse, however, it seemed a refresh fixed my problem.  See edit above.  Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Interesting... I've never heard about 'refresh' before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The error was that I needed to run a refresh before running mysqldump.exe. The command that did the trick was....

```
./mysqladmin.exe -u root -p refresh
```